# How to generate pseudo random string based on percentage probability?

Tags: python, random, python-3.6

I am new to python programming and currently working on python random module to generate pseudo random string based on probability.

I need to get random string based on probability that there should be 50% probability to get string "hello".

I have tried online to find solutions but not any luck and wasted much of time.

Please let me know if anyone has idea regarding my problem.

Comment: What about the rest of the time, i.e. the other 50%?

Comment: other 50% could be any string.

Comment: Generate a number from 0 to 1. If less than .5, generate "hello", else generate whatever random string you like. But somehow I doubt this example is representative of the problem you try to solve.

Comment: Does "any string" have any restriction of length?

Comment: @Xua, there is not any restriction of length of other string.

Comment: @Reti43, Thanks for your suggestion. this could be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are so many ways to do this.  Here is one:

```
import random
print(random.choice(['hello','other']))
```

if you want the other 50% of the time to get random strings, you can do this:

```
import random
r = random.choice(['hello','other'])
if r == "other":
    print(''.join(random.sample("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", 5)))
else:
    print(r)
```

Yet another way to do it is to use numpy.random.choice that allows you to assign weights that determine the likelihood that an element would be picked from a list.

```
import numpy as np

greetings = ['hello', 'good-bye', 'good morning', 'see you later', 'hi', 'bye']
weights = [0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
result = np.random.choice(greetings, p=weights)
print(result)
```

Comment: Here, 'other' should be any string not static 'other' value.

Comment: Ok.  See my amended solution.

Answer (score 0):

By take a random of two numbers. any number of the two have chance have 50% percent to be picked. so one of the number represent the the string "hello", and the other number another string

Here a simple example:

```
import random

a = random.randint(1, 2)
if a == 1:
    print("hello")
else:
    print("bye")
```

If you want that the other word will be random i can sugest 2 possible options:

- Create a list full of names and take a random one.
- Install a built in library that can create a random word like the library: random-word

For the first option i mentioned here an example of a code:

```
import random
other_words = ["whats up", "No problem", "See you later", "bye", "busy", "where are you", "have fun", "great"]
a = random.randint(1, 2)
if a == 1:
    print("hello")
else:
    print(random.choice(other_words))
```